# How to get a frequency count when first and last names are in dif columns in excel

Tags: excel, frequency-distribution

I have an Excel 2010 workbook with one row for Last name and one row for first name. There are approximately 1800 entries.

The same person (first and last name) can appear multiple times- jim simith appears 5 times. 
I want to do a frequency count of how many times jim simth appears in the list.

I used `=COUNTIF($B$2:$B$1800,B2)` , where `B` is the last name. The problem is that there are other Smiths in the list that are counted because the first name is in a separate column. Does anyone know how I could do a frequency count of each individual where their last names can be the same?

Comment: You could just use a pivot table

Answer (score 2):

`=COUNTIFS($B$2:$B$1800,B2,$A$2:$A$1800,A2)`

Comment: This will only work for Excel 2007+. For Excel 2003 and lower, use `=SUMPRODUCT(($B$2:$B$1800=B2)*($A$2:$A$1800=A2))`

Comment: This is true, however op specifically said it was a 2010 workbook

Comment: Yes he did -- it just wasn't tagged 2010, and so I wanted to make sure that someone who tries it with a different version doesn't get confused.

Comment: HI, this works but I found a new issue- one I dont believ can be solved without some natural language code. I have the same person with two different spellings of the first name or an added middle initial in the first name column. I think some data cleaning is in order. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this, and I'm assuming your `COUNTIF` formula works.

In a new column, you can [`CONCATENATE`](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/concatenate-function-HP010342288.aspx) the strings in the columns and run your `COUNTIF` on that.

Assuming that `A` is first name and `B` is last name, in `C` you'd have something like:

```
=CONCATENATE(A2, " ", B2)
```

And then you'd do the `COUNTIF` on that:

```
=COUNTIF($C2:$C1800,$C2)
```

Optionally, you may hide column `C` if you don't want it displayed.

Comment: @Rick I wasn't aware of the `&` operator in Excel, thanks for sharing! :)

Comment: You are welcome, I used concatenate for years before I realised you could just use `&`

Comment: Thanks. This worked as well but I have the same issue as I noted above in the first answer. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Probably overkill, but you can create an ADODB connection to the worksheet:

```vb
Dim conn As New Connection
With conn
    .Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
    .ConnectionString = "Data Source=""" & ActiveWorkbook.FullName & """;" & _
        "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=No;"""
    'If you're running a version of Excel earlier than 2007, the connection string should look like this:
    '.ConnectionString = "Data Source=""" & ActiveWorkbook.FullName & """;" & _
    '    "Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=No;"""
    .Open
End With
```

Then you can issue an SQL statement against the worksheet:

```vb
Dim rs As Recordset
Set rs = conn.Execute( _
    "SELECT F2 AS LastName, F1 AS FirstName, Count(*) AS C " & _
    "FROM [Sheet1$A$2:$B$1800] " & _
    "GROUP BY F2, F1" _
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This is a bit beyond my skill level.